# What was Bob blubbering about?

Tags: character, the-walking-dead

In this week's episode of The Walking Dead, towards the end of the episode Bob started, in my mind, acting funny.  He seems more emotional, and finally goes outside and starts crying while leaning up against a tree.

Does anyone know what caused this emotional breakdown?  Was it a near-death experience when they were in the food bank's basement?  Did he get bit while they were down there?  Is he just tired of killing walkers all the time?  Was it "that time of the month"?  OK, the last one's a goof...  :oP

What was Bob's deal?

Comment: You might get more mileage by posting a discussion question like this in IMDB's forum for the series. This question would require opinions, not really fact, because the why might be in future scripts (hasn't yet been revealed to us). Of course, if the why was already revealed in an earlier scene that you missed, then it might be completely and wholly answerable.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering; did I miss something.  My girlfriend was being a bit frisky when that was all going on...  ;)

Comment: Well, he's probably not happy that someone ate his left leg. More than likely it's from the experience of Terminus. Remember, he was a soldier and also a drunk. That provides too much to speculate with.

Comment: His left leg was still very much a part of him when he exited the church to have a good cry.

Comment: If you don't recall anything that happened before that moment in the episode that might have caused it, why not watch the episode again?

Comment: My guess was that he got bit by the walkers in the basement (when he got pulled under the water) and was getting ready to commit suicide.

Answer (score 5):

As was shown in last night's episode, "[Four Walls and A Roof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Walls_and_a_Roof)," **Bob was likely crying because he was, in fact, bitten by the walker that dragged him under the water earlier in the day**. He may have been contemplating suicide, and/or crying because he was building a relationship with Sasha and will now never get to fully see how it would turn out due to the bite.